# How to have state in sync in React multipage app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My App has this structure:

index.js renders App.js
App.js maintains routng to page 1 and page 2 and also kind of "global state" and methods which make state changes.

State (include methods) shares between page 1 and it's childs (componrnt a, b, c)as well as between page 2 through props, which receives on comp a, b, c and also page 2.

Changes that user applies in component a, b, c 'bubling' to app.js by callbacks, then state changes and goes back down reflecting these changes in UI and inner state on components a, b, c.

It works properly.

There's also nessessarity that these very cahnges in data structure reflects also in other app pages (currently on page 2).
So that page 2 also gets state changes throw props form app.js.

Though these logic doesn't work. Page 2 gets state only when app rendered first time but any further state ('props' in point of view of page 2) changes do not lead to any update of component on page 2, so it's just stuck on data it's got while app was initialized first time.

I'm newbie in React currently, and doesn't know much about Redux yet, though tell me please are there any other ways except using Redux to have this logic working properly ?

I do not use function in this project, only class approach.

```
                               index.js
                                  |
                               App.js 
                   (router to page 1 and page 2, 
              methods used by components on page 1, 
 state sharing through props to components on page 1 and page 2)
             /                               \
            /                                 \
       page 1                                 page 2
       / | \
      /  |  \
     /   |   \
   cmp1 cmp2 cmp3
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8acTv.jpg

Comment: Sounds like duplicated state

Comment: Page 2 components get it's state through props from app,js but isn't that true that changing in props is not nessessary for component updating ? So nevetheless state in app.js updates and sent down (by props) to page 2, components on page 2 doesn't update. I put componentDidMount() and componentDidUpdate() with a console logs everywhere through App instatnces so I can watch state and props updates and while within App->page 1 -> comp's of page 1 I'm keep watching all updates, on page 2 I notice only component mount and get props once app fired and no further updates.